# EXECUTE immediate and SQL Update

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help with this.  I am trying to execute this code in APEX using a dynamic action associated with a button.  Just trying to do a simple Update on the table, but my Pl/SQL is weak ;)

```
DECLARE
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt := 
'update dos_visits set visit_type = 'IMV'where     visit_type = 'SMV''
END;
```

I am getting a error with = for this ..

Thanks so much!

Comment: change 'SMV' to "SMV" and you should be through

Comment: @Satya, thats a bit unclear and doesnt handle `IMV`, tho its the correct answer.  Just post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL, single quotes in strings need to be escaped so that the PL/SQL engine knows that you want to indicate the presence of a single quote not to end the string.  If you want to use a variable `sql_stmt`, you'd also need to assign the value to that variable in a separate step from the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call.

This will work (note that these are two consecutive single quotes, not a single double quote character)

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'update dos_visits set visit_type = ''IMV'' where visit_type = ''SMV''';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt; 
END;
```

There doesn't appear, however, to be any reason to use dynamic SQL here.  It would generally make more sense to use static SQL

```
BEGIN
  update dos_visits 
     set visit_type = 'IMV' 
   where visit_type = 'SMV';
END;
```

If you are going to use dynamic SQL for some reason, you'd probably want to use bind variables in your query unless those `visit_type` values really are hard-coded.

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'update dos_visits set visit_type = :1 where visit_type = :2';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt 
    USING 'IMV', 'SMV'; 
END;
```

Comment: Hi,Really appreciate the quick answer here.  Thanks for help with the syntax.  The thing is when I run this in APEX, it does not update at all, the column is correct, the values are correct, the table is correct.  Not sure where this is getting tripped up.

Comment: oK ALL GOOD...sorry.I needed to do a committ in DEV first ;)  thanks again..big time!